# Is it possible to merge two borg repositories?

Tags: linux, backup, borg-backup

I use borg as a backup solution for my Linux machine.

I have two distinct borg repositories, let's call them

`/path/to/borg/repository/first/`

and

`/path/to/borg/repository/second/`

I need to merge these two repositories into a single one.

Is it possible to do so, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any officially endorsed method, but a possible approach could be to identify all the archives missing from one of the repositories and transfer them from the other using a combination of borg fuse and create.